# Ensure that a workflow in Github Actions is only ever triggered once

Tags: workflow, github-actions, github-cli

I have workflow that is triggered when a specific file is changed. Is it possible to ensure that this workflow is only triggered the first time that file is changed?

The use case is:

- a repository is created from a template repository
- to initialize the README and other things in the repo, some variables can be set in a JSON config file
- once that file is committed, the workflow runs, creates the README from a template etc.

I have tried to do let the workflow delete itself before it commits and pushes the changed files. That doesn't work: `fatal: not in a git directory` and `fatal: unsafe repository ('/github/workspace' is owned by someone else)`.

What might work is adding a topic like `initialized` to the repo at the end of the workflow and check for the presence of this topic at the beginning of the workflow. However, this is feels like a hack in that I'm abusing topics for something they're probably not meant to do.

So my question remains: is there a good way to only run the workflow once?

Comment: You could disable the workflow once it runs. Maybe you could try with adding `gh workflow disable -R <owner/repo>` as a last step. https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_disable

Comment: Thanks @frennky! Using the GitHub cli never occurred to me, but it works perfectly (see answer below)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the comment by [frennky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71872019/ensure-that-a-workflow-in-github-actions-is-only-ever-triggered-once#comment127028240_71872019) I managed to do solve this by using the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) to **disable the workflow**.

Here is the step at the end of the workflow that does this:

```yaml
- name: Disable this workflow
  shell: bash
  run: |
    gh workflow disable -R $GITHUB_REPOSITORY "${{ github.workflow }}"
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```